# How do I detect a breakpoint being deleted in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, vsx, envdte, vspackage

There doesn't seem to be any event in EnvDTE's [DebuggerEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.debuggerevents%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that notifies the consumer when a breakpoint is deleted. I've also looked at Visual Studio SDK and registered an IDebugEventCallback2, but no callback seems to be triggered when I deleted a breakpoint.

How can I get notified the moment the user deletes a breakpoint?

Comment: +1. I resorted to a timer polling DTE.Debugger.Breakpoints for changes :/

Answer (score 2):

Omer,

How frustrating. Can you try something like this?

```
#define BreakPoint12
#define BreakPoint13
//#define BreakPoint14
#define BreakPoint15

using system;
//...
//...

#if BreakPoint15

    // Team: Do not delete this breakpoint. Comment out definition.
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

#endif
```

Then you can at least keep track of where they are at.